# suspend funcion throw error about continuation parameter when using kotlin + spring

Tags: spring, kotlin-coroutines

I was trying to make a RestController using spring+kotlin which is simply as:

```
    @GetMapping("/test")
    suspend fun test(): Int {
        return 123
    }
```

And here is my relevant dependencies:

```
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux")
    implementation("org.springframework:spring-context")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-reactive")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-reactor")
```

However when I called it, it return with an error

```
"Invocation failure\nController [com.crypto.tax.admin.controller.AdminController]\nMethod [public final java.lang.Object com.********.test(kotlin.coroutines.Continuation<? super java.lang.Integer>)] with argument values:\n [0] [null] "
```

Is there any dependency missing or how could I get this up and running?

Comment: Please try [this starter](https://start.spring.io/#!type=gradle-project&language=kotlin&platformVersion=2.6.2&packaging=jar&jvmVersion=11&groupId=com.example&artifactId=demo&name=demo&description=Demo%20project%20for%20Spring%20Boot&packageName=com.example.demo&dependencies=webflux) (Gradle, kotlin, java11, webflux)

Answer (score 0):

Well, recreating my project from scratch was not an option, so I had to figure out what dependencies were missing that were causing the `Invocation failure` error.

It turns out those were the ones:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.projectreactor.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>reactor-kotlin-extensions</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlinx</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlinx-coroutines-reactor</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

After adding them, `suspend fun` controller methods started working nicely :)